# Terminal color scheme not working

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors

How can I reset gnome-terminal color scheme? My terminal not showing color difference when I use `ls` command. All files and directories shown in white. It's difficult to see which one is directory and which one is file. I don't know what exactly cause this problem. The problem comes from my linux installation before. For details what I have done that causes this problem is:

1. I install arch linux system.
2. I delete home partition and create a new one. There, gnome-terminal color scheme is not working for the first time.
3. I install Ubuntu with that arch home partition that I used before without formatting it. I think the settings carried on.
4. Then gnome-terminal color scheme have the same problem from the previous arch system.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

When you deleted your home partition, you may have removed the alias for `ls` that's configured by default, and which would be in `~/.bashrc`. Since you kept the same home directory when installing Ubuntu, this theory explains what you are experiencing.

To test whether this is the case, use

```
ls --color=auto
```

If this works correctly, you need to restore the default aliases and some other things, for this I suggest you just copy `/etc/skel/.bashrc` into your home directory (be careful if you've customized the `.bashrc` in your home dir).

This also depends on the `coreutils` package (for the `dircolors` utility), but that's installed in every ubuntu system so I'm pretty sure you're not missing that package.

Comment: It works. But, I just wondering, why it's not automatically generated when I install Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu is respecting your existing `.bashrc` (or if you didn't have one, it respects that fact as well), you wouldn't want Ubuntu to destroy it without asking :). It's only generated automatically from `/etc/skel` when you create a *new* user.

Comment: May your settings have been overwritten by `.profile_bash`. In this case `bashrc` is not loaded. That was my problem.

Comment: I was wondering how you came up with the solution.

Comment: @RatataTata *`.bash_profile`

Comment: @pdvries By knowing that `ls` has an alias in the `~/.bashrc` to enable color, and seeing the messy way OP handled the home partition

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the file `/etc/skel/.bashrc` into your home directory.

Then you also have to run `source ~/.bashrc` or launch a new shell to use the changes.

This worked on 16.04.